# Request for re-opening a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, community-faq

I posted this question, https://superuser.com/questions/491034/what-applications-have-a-version-for-modern-ui-and-desktop, which was closed.

I understand the reasoning; the answer is going to be a list. I did think it would be allowed though, because it's a finite list, we're not rating items in the list, it's not based on opinion and there is a definite answer. I look to questions like [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8) as an example of (what I think is) a question similar to mine that wasn't not closed.

I see it's been closed by one high-rep user and one moderator so clearly my understanding is wrong.

I guess my question is, what is it about my question that is different to the question highlighted above, that makes it close-worthy?

Comment: The list of shortcuts is unlikely to change, the list of software however...

Comment: Surely the list of software included **as part of the installation** will not change.

Comment: Good point. I'd still doubt the usefulness of such a list, but maybe someone else wants to offer an opinion as well :)

Comment: is there a practical use on being offered such a list? New shortcuts can be memorized and put to use, but I'm trying to think of a use for this list of apps. The [su] faq mentions - "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - [faq#dontask]

Comment: @Sathya: If I'm to support windows 8 remotely it'd be useful to know instances where a user could refer to 2 different versions of an application. Granted it's a narrow use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial feeling is no. And here's why:

1. Shortcuts are not likely to change while applications are. You state here that you wanted pre-packaged apps but to the traveling eye of your question that wasn't so clear.
2. What problem does this solve? What's the purpose in needing to know. Again shortcuts are useful for increasing efficiency and user performance but this is more of an informative list that says "hey that's cool".